# Android Sync Adapter not working on sdk 24 and above

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am new to android. And trying to add sync function in my application.
I checked the sync adapter to update app server with local SQLite DB. Checked from: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Server-Synchronization-(SyncAdapter)

After implementing the above code it is working fine with SDK 22 and below. But when tried with SDK 24 and above, it is not working.
I am trying to read data from SQLite DB in onPerformSync() and update to the app server.

Do I need to add any permission?

Note: I am using stub content provider.

```
@Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String 
    authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    Log.w(TAG, "jyoti: Starting synchronization...");

    //Class SyncingData is using to read data from local storage
    SyncingData syncingData = new SyncingData(getContext());
    syncingData.sync();

    Log.w(TAG, "Finished synchronization!");
}
```

Sync account is getting created in all SDK version (tried in SDK 22 and 25).
Sync is performing in SDK 22 but not in SDK 25.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in Adv.

Comment: i also facing same problem... if any one get solution...